# past tense or present perfect at the time of speaking

Tags: tense, past-tense, usage, present-perfect

My friend asked me about a person I never met in my life.

Should I say "I have never met him in my life." or "I never met him in my life."?

Comment: Welcome Amish, I'm not sure, but I think you are asking for "present tense" (I have met) vs. "past tense" (I met), not for "past participle".

Comment: For this question, like for many past tense/present perfect questions, both alternatives are fine.

Comment: @Carlo_R. "I have met" is present perfect: subject + have/has + past tense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the past and the present perfect express basically the same thing, so *semantically* it doesn't really matter which you use.

Other things being equal, answers very often reflect the form of the question. For instance:

> SHE: Surely you met him last August?
> YOU: No, I never met him in my life. ... *your past tense matches hers*
>
> SHE: You've met him, haven't you?
> YOU: No, I've never met him in my life. ... *your present perfect matches hers*

This is not by any means a rule; but it may help you in conversation.